# Editors for Windows with automatic completion, environments etc

Tags: miktex, windows, auto-completion, ide

My "home" environment is GNU Emacs under Linux with AucTeX and RefTeX; as far as I'm concerned this is the perfect environment for LaTeX editing.  And I've written books, papers, notes for students, innumerable other documents over the years.

However, at work I'm constrained with Windows 10.  I have experimented with VirtualBox and Linux but that's a bit of a pain, as well as a strain on system resources.  So I'm looking for a Windows TeX IDE, that has similar functionality to Emacs.  I know there is an Emacs for Windows, but as far as I can tell it's a bit of a kludge, using cygwin or some other library to shoehorn Emacs into Windows.  I'm looking for a more native application.

Is there one such?

Comment: There is VIM for Windows.

Comment: To me this is a dupe

Answer (score 1):

You can use cygwin (it's what I do, I also use the cygwin texlive) but the native windows build of emacs is also fine (you should use that one if using the native windows texlive as then the filesystem roots match up) or of course you can use ubuntu texlive and and emacs in the windows 10 subsystem for linux which comes with windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

TexMaker is my companion with Windows 10. It does perfectly what you are looking for and is updated regularly. Installation is as simple as possible with a lot of options to meet your requirements.